# HTML speacial character parsing

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, web-scraping

I'm looking for a java class to parse all HTML special characters.
I guess it's a common problem but i cannot find a fast solution right now.

What i wanto to get is:

```
input: th&egrave; --> output: thè
input: &#187;
input: &lraquo;
...
```

Do you know anything useful for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the StringEscapeUtils utility class. Check the docs for the StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml() method.

Docs here:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Download here:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/

Answer (score 0):

Have you googled on it? The first link on "java HTML markup entity parser" refers to
[html text extractor](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/TextExtractor.html)

It seems to be what you need.

Also, you may want to examine javax.swing.JLabel's (and another swing text components') renderers.